# sweetalert2 no funciona o no responde en el if o else

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

Hola estoy implementando un sistema de registro de mascotas y quiero que al momento de enviar el formulario envíen un mensaje de éxito, estoy utilizando sweetalert2, he logrado hacer la condición, pero al momento de poner el código de sweetalert2 en el if no me responde, me gustaría me ayuden.

```
 <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col">
         <button
             type="submit"
             class="btn btn-perro btn-block"
             data-toggle="modal"
             data-target="#modalCambio"
             onclick="enviarExitoCambio()">
             Enviar Solicitud
         </button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Función

```
function enviarExitoCambio() {
    let direccionNuevDueCamb = 
    document.getElementById("direccionNuevDueCambio").value;
    if (direccionNuevDueCamb == "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        Swal.fire(
            'The Internet?',
            'That thing is still around?',
            'question')
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qué error te muestra la consola del navegador?

Comment: Ningún error, no ejecuta la consulta

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo por aquí otra forma :

```js
document.getElementById("PRUEBA").onclick = function() {enviarExitoCambio()};

function enviarExitoCambio() {
  let direccionNuevDueCam = document.getElementById("direccionNuevDueCambio").value;
  if (direccionNuevDueCam != "") {
    Swal.fire(
      'The Internet?',
      'That thing is still around?',
      'question'
    )
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
<div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4">
                      <label for="dire-nuevo-dueño">Dirección</label>
                      <input
                        data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-placement="bottom"
                        title="Este campo es obligatorio"
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="* Su dirección"
                        id="direccionNuevDueCambio"
                        onclick = "addClassDireNuevDueCambio()"
                      />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-perro btn-block"
                        data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#modalCambio"
                        id="PRUEBA"
                      >
                        Enviar Solicitud
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Te explico todo funciona, pero al momento de enviar el mensaje aparece fugazmente, quiere decir que para que aparezca el mensaje tiene que validar los campos, todo eso hace pero como te explico el mensaje aparece fugazmente.

Comment: porque le tienes puesto un return false y eso es lo que devuelve, quita el return false y el mensaje permanece hasta que hagas click en aceptar, cerrar o el boton que tu definas

Comment: Estimado lo mismo en fin...

Comment: como? no te entiendo, yo uso sweet alert en alguna pagina que tengo por ahí y simplemente estas comprobando que la direccion no este vacia, y te devuelve null, y si esta rellena te muestra el sweet alert y te devuelve null. y eso lo hace correctamente, otra cosa es que tu quieras que haga otra cosa... pero como no nos lo expliques....

Comment: Te explico estamos en un proyecto en la cual se tiene que registrar mascotas, estamos en el formulario que solicitan cambio de titularidad de la mascota, ya hemos hecho el código para que valide los campos, entonces al momento de enviar el formulario debe de aparecer una alerta que se le dice gracias pronto nos pondremos en contacto con usted, pero para realizar eso se tiene que validar el ultimo campó que es la dirección, quiere decir que si encuentra texto lo envía y aparece la alerta, si no tuviera texto no debe de hacer nada.

Comment: y asi lo hace..... por lo menos a mi solo me muestra la alerta cuando esta rellena la direccion.... lo he puesto en el snippet

Comment: lamentablemente el mio no, si quieres te doy la dirección de gitlab para que lo revises.

Comment: pero has probado el snippet que te he pasado en esta respuesta?

Comment: Todo mi estimado..

Comment: Hola, al parecer el problema esta en el formularios que al momento de enviar limpia todo el formulario, pero cuando pongo un alert funciona con normalidad.

Comment: porque el submit envia el formuladrio por eso es necesario cambiar el type=submit a type=button o poner el preventDefault() para que no realice la funcion de submitir

Answer (score 0):

prueba cambiando el `type="submit"` por `type="button"` para que el boton ejecute sus eventos como el `onclick`. El tipo `submit` lanza el metodo `submit()` del formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Les dejo el código a que me ayuden, lamentablemente no me funciona

```js
function enviarExitoCambio(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  let direccionNuevDueCam = document.getElementById("direccionNuevDueCambio").value;
  if (direccionNuevDueCam !== "") {
    Swal.fire(
      'The Internet?',
      'That thing is still around?',
      'question'
    )
    return false
  } else {

    return false;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4">
                      <label for="dire-nuevo-dueño">Dirección</label>
                      <input
                        data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-placement="bottom"
                        title="Este campo es obligatorio"
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="* Su dirección"
                        id="direccionNuevDueCambio"
                        onclick = "addClassDireNuevDueCambio()"
                      />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-perro btn-block"
                        data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#modalCambio"
                        onclick="enviarExitoCambio()" 
                      >
                        Enviar Solicitud
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: te he dejado otra forma en mi respuesta que la he probado